# What SE site for asking questions about color extraction

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a such site to ask *"What are the purposes of color extraction using K-means"*?

Explanation: [*k*-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) is a vector quantization algorithm; color extraction is the process of getting colors from an image.

I'm not talking about any software, only the purposes of color extraction.

Comment: See also: ["What are the main differences between K-means and K-nearest neighbours?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/56500/197829) and ["What K is in KNN and K-Means"](https://ealizadeh.com/blog/knn-and-kmeans/#:~:text=KNN%20is%20a%20supervised%20learning%20algorithm%20mainly%20used%20for%20classification,on%20the%20chosen%20distance%20metric\).), so it could be more suitable for stats.SE; if the other K is what was meant.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing).

I see tags for:

- [image-processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)
- [quantization](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantization)
- [k-means](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/k-means)
- [color](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color)